# Javascript search for an object key in a set

Tags: javascript, search, set, key

Is it possible to use the javascript "Set" object to find an element with a certain key?
Something like that:

```
let myObjects = [{"name":"a", "value":0}, {"name":"b", "value":1},{"name":"c", "value":2}];
let mySet = new Set(myObjects);
console.log(mySet.has({"name":"a"}));
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Not in that way, that would look for the specific object you're passing in, which isn't in the set.

If your starting point is an array of objects, you don't need a `Set` at all, just `Array.prototype.find`:

```js
let myObjects = [{"name":"a", "value":0}, {"name":"b", "value":1},{"name":"c", "value":2}];
let found = myObjects.find(e => e.name === "a");
console.log(found);
```

If you already have a `Set` and want to search it for a match, you can use its iterator, either directly via `for-of`:

```js
let myObjects = [{"name":"a", "value":0}, {"name":"b", "value":1},{"name":"c", "value":2}];
let mySet = new Set(myObjects);
let found = undefined; // the `= undefined` is just for emphasis; that's the default value it would have without an initializer
for (const e of mySet) {
  if (e.name === "a") {
    found = e;
    break;
  }
}
console.log(found);
```

...or indirectly via `Array.from` to (re)create (the)an array, and then use `find`:

```js
let myObjects = [{"name":"a", "value":0}, {"name":"b", "value":1},{"name":"c", "value":2}];
let mySet = new Set(myObjects);
let found = Array.from(mySet).find(e => e.name === "a");
console.log(found);
```

---

If it's something you need to do often, you might give yourself a utility function for it:

```js
const setFind = (set, cb) => {
  for (const e of set) {
    if (cb(e)) {
      return e;
    }
  }
  return undefined; // undefined` just for emphasis, `return;`
                    // would do effectively th same thing, as
                    // indeed would just not having a `return`
                    // at at all
}

let myObjects = [{"name":"a", "value":0}, {"name":"b", "value":1},{"name":"c", "value":2}];
let mySet = new Set(myObjects);
let found = setFind(mySet, e => e.name === "a");
console.log(found);
```

You could even put that on `Set.prototype` (making sure it's non-enumerable), but beware of conflicting with future additions to `Set` (for instance, I wouldn't be *at all* surprised if `Set.prototype` got a `find` method at some point).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, my question was simply out of curiosity, as I have read somewhere that searching in a `Set` object has a complexity of O(1).

Comment: *checking if sth is in it* !== *searching*

Comment: @Jonasw: True! Alexandre, if you just want a boolean result, use `some` rather than `find` above (and adjust the `for-of` accordingly).

Comment: @AlexandreSenges searching a set is O(1) if you have *the original* item. With primitives (`new Set([1, 2, 3])`) you don't need the original as `2 === 2` but with objects you can't do it as `{} !== {}`. You can't lookup an arbitrary property of an arbitrary object in a set at O(1) complexity without having reference to the original object...at which point you don't need to look it up in the set.

Answer (score 7):

You may just want a Set of names:

```
 let myObjects = [{"name":"a", "value":0}, {"name":"b", "value":1},{"name":"c", "value":2}];

let map = new Set(myObjects.map(el=>el.name));
console.log(map.has("a"));
```

If you want to get an object by name,thats what a *Map* is for:

```
let myObjects = [{"name":"a", "value":0}, {"name":"b", "value":1},{"name":"c", "value":2}];

let map = new Map(myObjects.map(el=>[el.name,el]));
console.log(map.get("a"));
```

Comment: While `Map` works, this is what a *set* is for: `let mySet = new Set(myObjects.map(e => e.name)); console.log(mySet.has("a"));` (if we're going to solve it that way).

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do this with a Set, then the object you're searching for has to be the same object that was added, not an anonymous object.

So, you could achieve what you're looking for if it was set up like this:

```
let myObject = {"name": "a", "value": 0};
let set = new Set([myObject]);

console.log(set.has(myObject));
```

This is because `set.has()` uses `SameValueZero()` under the hood.

Here is the spec for `set.has()`: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-set.prototype.has

And for `SameValueZero()`: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-samevaluezero

Comment: This doesn't do what the OP asked. The question quite clearly has two separate objects (one in the array, and a **different** one being searched for), not a single object.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer - no. `Set.has` operates on object equality, and each object in the list is unique - so when you pass a new object to `.has` it will not return `true`, even if it has the same keys and values.

You could always filter the original list, and if the resulting list has a length greater than zero, your object will be contained within.

```
const containsObjectWithName = ({ name }) => 
  !!myObjects
    .filter((obj) => obj.name === name)
    .length;

containsObjectWithName({ name: 'a' });  // true
```

Answer (score 1):

*Actually a response to [Efficiently find an item in a Set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55077938/efficiently-find-an-item-in-a-set) but they've closed it as a duplicate #ftw*

An alternative approach:

```
class ArraySet extends Set {

    find(predicate) {
        for(var x of this)
            if (predicate(x)) return x;
        return undefined;
    },

    ... other Array.prototype stuff here

}

const things = new ArraySet([
    { x: 1 },
    { y: 2 }
]);

const found = things.find(item => item.y === 2);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
      var myObj = { "A": "1", "B": "2", "C": "3" }
      var objLength = Object.keys(myObj).length

      var firstKeyOfObject = Object.keys(myObj)[0]
      var firstValueOfObject = myObj[Object.keys(myObj)[0]]
      var lastKeyOfObject = Object.keys(myObj)[objLength - 1]
      var lastValueOfObject = myObj[Object.keys(myObj)[objLength - 1]]
      

      console.log('firstKeyOfObject', firstKeyOfObject)
      console.log('firstValueOfObject', firstValueOfObject)
      console.log('lastKeyOfObject', lastKeyOfObject)
      console.log('lastValueOfObject', lastValueOfObject)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want your solution to be performant, use `Map` instead of `Set`.
If your `Set` is not that big you can go with [T.J. Crowder solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45389162/2336607) and convert `Set` to `Array` then filter and vice versa.

```
let myObjects = [['a',{"name":"a", "value":0}], ['b',{"name":"b", "value":1}],['c',{"name":"c", "value":2}]];
let myMap = new Map(myObjects);
console.log(myMap.has('a'));
```