# Efficiently find an item in a Set

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, set

if I need to find an object in a Set. The set does not contain a natural key to use as an index, so I can't use Map. There are several different types of predicates used to search the Set. It seems inefficient to do

```
const items = Array.from( mySet )
const found = items.find( item => someTest( item ) )
```

Unless there's black magic in the optimiser, it seems like it will enumerate twice. I know it exposes an iterator interface, but the Array.prototype.find interface is much more concise than using a for...of loop with a break statement.

Is there a better way?

Comment: As a side-note - if you find yourself having to search through Sets a lot, perhaps you should use a Map to store the values.

Comment: yeah @VLAZ but what if you need more than one index?

Comment: Ah, that's tough. You could buildup lookup tables for each but I do get your pain. I actually have a similar problem right now - I've objects with three properties each and want to look them up by two of those (one at a time, though, so either propA or propB). It's not in JS but it doesn't matter that much. I've yet to solve it efficiently.

Comment: Ugh. this isn't a duplicate of the referenced question. I'm talking about search with a predicate, not a lookup key situation.

Comment: There is no way to look up stuff in a set with a predicate. All you can do is iterate through it and test manually against the predicate then return the one that matches. So while the premise of your question not match the other one, that's the only solution. The accepted answer even has a suggestion for a helper function to do that.

Comment: I'm asking for "a better way" - the answer is either "no" or some new solution

Comment: Well the better solution is to iterate through the set instead of making an array from it. This ensures you only iterate once. That question is how you do the once iteration, plus it has an implementation for a helper function you can give an arbitrary set and abitrary predicate to fetch any item from it. So, the answer to your question is "yes" as there is a more efficient way to do it, and the dupe is that more efficient way including an implementation for exactly what you want - a lookup by predicate.

Comment: ah ok my bad i didn't see an example suggesting a helper function - are you referring to the example at the bottom of https://stackoverflow.com/a/45389162/275501 ? It works but I was thinking along the lines of e.g. a custom iterator which would adapt an underlying Set to allow find plus other types of Array.prototype functions.

Comment: Yes, the example at the bottom is what I'm referring to. It would definitely be cool to be able to interact with a set like it's an array - calling `.filter` and `.map` on it, for example but I don't think that's actually *conceptually* what a set is about. These operations would most likely need to build a new set for the output. Maybe not for `.filter`, since you have `.delete()` on a set but mapping need it. Imagine if you have `mySet = new Set([1, 2, 3])` and do `mySet.map(x => x * 2)` - if you re-use the set what happens when you do `mySet.delete(1); mySet.add(2)`

Comment: If the array prototype methods are being used to inspect the set (rather than modify it), i think an array as output is probably acceptable. But yeah, obviously the entire Array.prototype protocol isn't all the useful for a Set.

Comment: Another solution would be to `extend` Set (which I've suggested in the so-called duplicate question)

Answer (score 2):

You have [**has**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/has) method on Set to find existence of value.

```js
let set = new Set([1,2,4,5,6,7])

console.log(set.has(2))
console.log(set.has(10))
```

Comment: ok i should clarify in my question that the items are objects, not primitives

Comment: I assume OP has, say `{id: 1}` and `{id:2}` and wants to do `item => item.id == 1` or something along those lines.

Comment: This is correct. However you can't verify via `has` that there is at least one element in a `Set` that _pass_ a predicate.

Comment: @goofballLogic can i see an example Set please ? at first instance it seemed to me that what you're looking for is `has` but by your comment it seems you're after something else

Answer (score 2):

Sets implement the iterator interface, so you should be able to iterate them looking for your particular item. It will not be as nice and declarative as using a find with an hig order function, with will be much more efficient.
You can of course encapsulate that logic to make it much nicer

```
const findInSet = (pred, set) => { 
    for (let item of set) if(pred(item)) return item;
}
const item = findInSet(someTest, mySet);
```

Comment: yeah it seems like this will be more efficient, but as you say - not as nice. was hoping to have my cake and eat it too

Comment: well, once you have it encapsulated you can use other FP libraries and functionalities and you will not even notice that is not as nice :D

Answer (score 1):

Use a Map instead with the id (unique identifier) as the key:

```js
const items = [{ id: 1 }, { id: 2 }, { id: 3 }]
const itemsMap = new Map(items.map(o => [o.id, o]))

const item = itemsMap.get(1)

console.log(item)
```

Comment: yeah thought of this too, but i don't always find using the same predicate so this would only help in one specific instance of find